# C# Counting numbers & letters

Tags: c#, counting

I want to count how many numbers (*only 0,1,2,3*) and letters (*a,b,c,d*) were used in a line that I'm checking - they are mixed, for example: **3b1c1c1a1a0b1a1d3d0a3c**. How can I count that?

Comment: how many of each, or in total?

Comment: `string.GroupBy(str => str.IsDigit).Select(g => g.Count()).ToList()` - Untested but the first number should be numbers, and the second letters

Comment: @Timothy, actually nothing important yet, because every single one wasn't working properly, @.Vixen how many in total, sorry @.user3596113 Ah sorry for mentioning it, it's not actually important. It's a single line of a .txt file @.Sayse: "'string' does not contain a definition for 'GroupBy'". Am I missing something? Sorry I don't usually write anything in c#

Comment: @DenisWasilew for `string` variable you will get `GroupBy`.

Comment: @DenisWasilew - See Ians answer, but in honesty, I prefer David Pilkingtons answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int numbers = 0;
int letters = 0;

foreach(char a in myString)
{
  if (Char.IsDigit(a))
    numbers ++;
  else if (Char.IsLetter(a)){
    letters ++;
}
```

Comment: Looks like it's the solution for my problem. Thanks you very much for your help, I will accept it in 4 minutes.

Comment: @Vixen - that is *not* a valid edit, you completely changed his answer. You should suggest things like that for David, not implement them.

Comment: @Vixen there are no other numbers than 0,1,2,3 so I think there is no need to check if they are 0,1,2,3, the first solution works fine. Thanks again all of you guys.

Comment: @DenisWasilew, it was not clear if you only wanted to count 0,1,2,3 or if only those existed

Answer (score 1):

You could also use predefined Linq expressions if these need to be re-used:

```
var characterList = "234234abce".ToCharArray();
var validCharacters = "0123abcd".ToCharArray();

Func<char, bool> ValidLetter = delegate(char c){
    return Char.IsLetter(c) && validCharacters.Contains(c);
};
Func<char, bool> ValidNumber = delegate(char c){
    return Char.IsDigit(c) && validCharacters.Contains(c);
};

var letterCount = characterList.Where(c => ValidLetter(c)).Count();
var numberCount = characterList.Where(c => ValidNumber(c)).Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a method for doing that:

```
int count = myString.ToCharArray().Where(c => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)).Count();
```

If you want to split them out then:

```
int letterCount = myString.ToCharArray().Where(c => Char.IsLetter(c)).Count();
int numberCount = myString.ToCharArray().Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c)).Count();
```

If you want to filter them based on the numbers:

```
 List<char> searchFor = new List<char>() { '0', '1', '2', '3' };
 int numberCount = myString.ToCharArray().Where(c => searchFor.Contains(c)).Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ASCII code to get it work

```
             for(int i = 0 ; i < str.Length ; i++){
             int asciicode = (int)str[i];
             if(asciicode >= 48 && asciicode <= 57)
                        number++;
             else
                      alphabet++;                 
      }
```

Comment: .NET's System.String type holds a counted array of Unicode/UTF-16 code-units (`char` type value). Individual UTF-16 code-units do not necessarily represent a codepoint (a numeric identifier for a character in a character set) because UTF-16 encodes some of the Unicode characters with two code-units (called surrogate pairs, one "high" and one "low"). High and low surrogate and unpaired code-units have distinct ranges so you can achieve this specific goal by inspecting individual code-units because the eight characters being sought are all single code-unit codepoints.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example to find the count of character "1":

```
        string input = "3b1c1c1a1a0b1a1d3d0a3c";
        int count = input.ToArray().Count(i => i == '1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Below meets your requirements:

```
string acceptedChars = "0123abcd";

var res = "3b1c1c1a1a0b1a1d3d0a3c".ToCharArray()
    .Where(x => acceptedChars.Contains(x))
    .GroupBy(x => char.IsDigit(x))
    .Select(g => new{ isDigit = g.Key, count = g.Count() } );

var digitsCount = res.Single(r => r.isDigit == true).count;
var lettersCount = res.Single(r => r.isDigit == false).count;
```